# Reference a data validation?

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I am trying to produce a sheet where a certain cell will contain a fixed value or a dropdown, depending on another cell's value. I would do this by using match&index to reference specific parts of a 'backend' sheet, but referencing a cell doesn't copy the data validation/dropdown, only its final value.

Is there a way to reference the data validation of one cell to another?

Comment: Hi there @ThanosMaravel, so by referencing a data validation you mean having access to all the data in the data validation? Or you want to keep the format of the cell with the dropdown?

Comment: Hopefully, to cause the referencing cell to exhibit the dropdown as well. This would let me freely adapt the options of the dropdown by dependency (which I can already do with some roundabout work), but also to avoid dropdowns with a single option (by defaulting that option to plaintext).

Answer (score 1):

data validation in google sheets can be accessed only from a given cell that already contains a data validation rule, hence there is no referencing system in place. if you want to clone/apply your data validation rule across range you can either drag/copy the cell that contains the rule or set the data validation globally imputing a range under data validation